# Laravel error: MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to to let the customer to update their already registered account. They register by validating their **Registration_Code**, for now all works fine but when I try to fill the form and save it I get **MethodNotAllowedHttpException** error.

Follows the code below

**routes.php**

[image]

**controller.php**

[image]

**registration view** : Works fine

[image]

**Customer Pre-filled Form**: On save I get **MethodNotAllowedHttpException**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Form action and the route http request do not match up one is PUT, while other is POST

POST is used to create and your route says:

```
Route::post
```

PUT can be used to create and update

Comment: Opss, you are right :) but when I change it to **PUT** this time I am getting this Error **Creating default object from empty value** ? @Aleksei Maide

Comment: I think it is because of your request not having any value defined for the $id variable (it should either come from form with the request or in the URL /{id} as a result the $customer variable is an empty value

Comment: I already pass the $id value When the Admin edit and update the customer info on Admin panel. But here in front end I don't to pass any Id to the route, I only want them update their pre-filled info and then proceed to next step.